# How to remove borders in a sizeable form?

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms, aero

I'm trying to remove the borders, from a sizeable form.
I've tried **FormBorderStyle** = **None** but it's not what I'm searching for, since it removes the **Aero snap support**, **Aero shake support**, etc...

What I have in the moment, is the WinForm **without the ControlBox/Titlebar** with a Panel, so the user can move the application while clicking the panel. [Application ATM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rgRO.gif) (I want to be able to do this, without the WinForm borders).

Is there anyway to make the form "borderless", without ruining the Aero Snap Support?

Comment: Would making the background of the form transparent work for you?

Comment: Not exactly. At the moment, I'm not using the background of the application for anything, but in the future I plan to add controls on it. However, making the background transparent, will keep the borders anyways. [Example](https://imgur.com/a/eIg6iam)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. But after doing this, you have to create functions for dragging, minimizing and closing the form.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.ControlBox = False
    Me.Text = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Like I've said, I've tried **FormBorderStyle = None** before, it's not what I'm searching for.

Comment: I've said that too: "**What I have in the moment**, is the WinForm **without the ControlBox/Titlebar** [...]". You can check the image that I posted, that's what I already have..

Comment: In my suggestion, put here in form load:   Dim p As New Drawing2D.GraphicsPath(): p.AddRectangle(New Rectangle(8, 8, Me.Width - 16, Me.Height - 16)): Me.Region = New Region(p)

Comment: Sorry if it will not work, but if it can work, adjust the constant 8 and 16 according your need, where 8 is assumption of border size and 16 is 2 * border size

Comment: Another way, you can use System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint to draw title, max button, min button, close button, and DrawString to title rect when yo set FormBorderStyle = None

Comment: Adding the code that you suggested, will result this: [Drawing2D](https://imgur.com/a/pBkcAsQ), which is not quite what I'm looking for.. And yes, I could draw the Maximize Btn, Minimize and Close button, but the moment that I set my **FormBorderStyle = None** I will lose every support from **Aero**.